# Find an example of a two-rule concave function with specific conditions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, convex-analysis, special-functions

Let $f:[1,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a concave function such that $ \displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(f(n)-f(n+1)=0$ and the derivative of the function $f$ does not exist. I am looking for an example of a two-rule function that in addition to the above conditions.

My attempt:
Define the function $f:[1,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{align*}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\log x &; x\geq 2 \text{}\\
\frac{2}{3}x + \log 2 - \frac{4}{3} &; 1\leq x < 2 \text{}
\end{cases} 
\end{align*}
This function is concave and $ \displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(f(n)-f(n+1))=0$ from a number on. There are two problems in this example: First, the function does not have a left-hand limit at $x=2$ . Secondly,  $ \displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(f(n)-f(n+1))=0$ is from a number on, whereas I want $ \displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(f(n)-f(n+1)=0$ in  $[1,+\infty)$. Can anyone guide me and give an example with the above conditions?. Thanks

Comment: What does *“$\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(n)-f(n+1))=0$ is from a number on”* mean? – Also the left limit $\lim_{x \to 2^-} f(x) = \log 2$ does exist.

Comment: Excuse me Martin, corrected sentence: the function does not have a left-hand derivative at $x=2$.

Comment: Also, Since $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}(f(n)-f(n+1))$ does not  zero in $1\leq x < 2$,

Comment: Sorry, but that makes no sense. For the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(n)-f(n+1))$ it is irrelevant how the function is defined on $[1, 2)$.

Comment: Thanks. With the above conditions, can you give an example?

Comment: Martin R. With the above conditions, can you give an example?